# Howto select an inner link in a table row

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to select a link in a html row when I have the hover on it, I'm probably doing it wrong.

Here is my HTML:

```
<table id="table-id">
<tr>
    <td>yeah</td>
    <td>some content</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="remove">delete</a></td>
</tr>
...
</table>
```

And the jQuery code:

```
$('#table-id tr').hover(function(){
    $(this).children('.remove').show(); # I don't get the link in there
}, function(){
    $(this).children('.remove').hide(); # and thus not here neither
});
```

The links was hidden with:

```
$('a.remove').each(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).click(function(){
        return confirm("are you sure?");
    });
});
```

Any ideas about what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The direct children of the `tr` are `td` elements, thus it doesn't work.
You can use something like this:

```
  $('#table-id tr').hover(function(){
        $(this).children().find(".remove").show(); 
    }, function(){
        $(this).children().find(".remove").hide(); 
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R7vY5/

Comment: You could just use `this` as the [context for the selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context): `$('.remove', this)`.

Comment: You dont even need to get the children and find in it just `$(this).find(".remove")` or @Chris's suggestion is enough.

Answer (score 2):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pkPbe/2)

You can use `.find('.remove')`

```
$('#table-id tr').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.remove').show();
}, function(){
    $(this).find('.remove').hide();
});
```